# nesting forms without using partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know if the code below is good.

```
% form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_field :question %>
     <% builder.fields_for :answers do |answer|
     <p>Answer: <%= answer.text_field :answer %>
     <% end %>
 <% end %>

  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Is this piece if code `<%= builder.text_field :question %>` good?

Am asking this because when i render my form, nothing is displayed for answer and when i view page source, i don't have anything for the answer section.

Many many thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<% form_for @survey do |f| %>
```

with:

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
```

and the same here:

```
<% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
```

to be replaced by:

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
```

I guess you've understood you have to proceed again with `answers`:)